# What is radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics

So, I was in my grade 7 class and we studied about radiation. The teacher was saying radiation is when **heat is transferred without any molecules being involved**, like the sun. But in another post online someone else had said radiation is when **heat is transferred with the heat source being hotter than it's enviroment**, like an oven or a fire.      **Which is true?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the first.

One reason is that the second includes conduction, and therefore loses the distinction between the two.  I think I would modify the first by saying *energy* is transferred without any molecules being involved.  It's hard to see how one would talk about heat transfer for laser radiation or beta radiation where the temperature of the source is not well defined.

I will admit that a good definition of radiation would be hard to construct.  But an essential feature would be the ability to transfer energy through a vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

Most would agree that the first statement is reasonably accurate, perhaps, more so, if "heat" is replaced by "energy", as suggested by garyp.

But I'd like to make a comment regarding the second statement. An important point here is that a body will radiate as long as its temperature is greater than the absolute zero, regardless of the temperature of the surrounding environment, e.g., air. In other words, to radiate, the body does not have to be hotter than the environment.

With that said, the net heat transfer could be going in the other direction. For instance, if we take a glass of milk out a refrigerator and put it on a table, the net heat (through conduction, convection and radiation from other objects), will be transferred from the environment to the glass of milk, but it will still radiate.

Comment: Which means radiation is happening all the time and the term is very stupid?

Comment: Not sure what is stupid about the term, but yes - all objects, at temperatures above the absolute zero, radiate something all the time.

Comment: OK, what do they radiate? Cuz that's my question, rlly. What is radiation? What gets... Radiated??

Comment: It's electromagnetic waves of different frequencies. For instance, heat is radiated out in the infrared range.

Comment: Oh. Makes better sense, I guess.... I just never thought that my own body is "radiating". Seems a lil scary now.

Comment: I can assure you it does. Now that you know, you'll get used to it:)

Comment:  oh man, wish u nvr said that.

Comment: How did u get that much reputation!?

Comment: By answering questions like yours and, sometimes, getting up votes from people who found my answers useful.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are true but the second one is more general and applies to both conduction and radiation.

If you heat up a metal rod at one end, the other end will get warmer as well because the heat is transmitted from the hot end to the cold end and never the other way round.

Heat can also be transmitted by radiation even through empty space - that's a good thing, just think about the sun.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, radiation is the emission of electromagnetic waves from a source.

What does this mean in practice however?

EM waves do not require a medium to propagate, so in the case of definition 1, that is true that radiation travels through a vacuum (without a medium or molecules to conduct them).

The other major forms of heat transfer are conduction (through more or less static objects) and convection (through moving fluids), since radiation does not require a medium to conduct its energy, it falls outside of either of these explicitly.

In regards to definition 2, it's kind of a definition of heat, temperature is the average molecular kinetic energy, heat is what transfers that energy to or from a source.  This means that if you have a fire for example, there is heat transfer from the fire, if you have an ice cube, there is heat transfer to the cube.

Since radiation is just EM energy and can exist at many different wavelengths and amplitudes, you have to use a general definition of EM waves traveling outward from a source, a lot of the observed effects like temperature, heat, color, etc. tend to have more to do with the band of radiation you are working with.
For a brief overview of the types of radiation, there is a good explanation here.
https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/toolbox/emspectrum1.html

Comment: I understand what u r saying, but I still don't understand what radiation is!

Comment: Strictly speaking, _electromagnetic radiation_ is the emission of electromagnetic waves... More broadly speaking, _radiation_ is the emission of _energy_ that travels in "rays" (i.e., straight lines that radiate outward from a _source_.) The energy can be carried by photons (electromagnetic radiation), by subatomic particles (e.g., "beta rays"), by waves propagating through a medium (e.g., acoustic radiation).